# compare file content in folder using windows batch

Tags: batch-file, compare

I've been struggling with this for several days... there is one folder with a lot txt files with random names that are generated from server timestamps, but content of files must not be identical for two files in that folder! any ideas? my only option is using windows batch

Comment: Please put few lines of code, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you use some downloadable free command line tools for use in a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO (
 FOR %%c IN (*.*) DO IF /i "%%~nxa" lss "%%~nxc" IF "%%~za"=="%%~zc" (
  FC "%%a" "%%c" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "%%a" and "%%c" are identical

 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` and of the filemask `*.*` to suit your circumstances.

---

Revision for only-one-mention-of-a-duplicate-file

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO (
 SET "reported="
 FOR %%c IN (*.*) DO IF NOT DEFINED reported IF /i "%%~nxa" lss "%%~nxc" IF "%%~za"=="%%~zc" (
  FC /b "%%a" "%%c" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "%%a" and "%%c" are identical&SET reported=Y
 )
)
```

GOTO :EOF

I've also added `/b` to `fc` to allow for non-text files.

Comment: `"%%~nxa" lss "%%~nxc"` will do an ascii compare, wouldn't you use `NEQ` instead?  I use a script that compares identical filesizes and does an MD5 checksum on those files and compares the hashes.  For large files it is far more efficient.

Comment: @foxidrive if you use `NEQ` the same pair of files will be compared twice. "a-b" and "b-a"

Comment: great! had to modify a little because turns out that there are some files that must be identical =] added:
for /f %%q in ('findstr /M "^4;" C:\zzd\*.txt') do (move "%%q" c:\temp)

Comment: @Stephan I don't follow.  How does lss work in this case?   It's comparing filenames and you'd either use EQU or NEQ wouldn't you?

Comment: @foxidrive er, no. As Stephan has it. The nested `for`s apply the full set of matching filenames to `%%a` and `%%c`. Certainly, `"%%a" NEQ "%%c"` would stop any attempt to compare a file to itself *but* suppose for example we have `f1` and `f2`. When `%%a`= f1 and `%%c`= f2, then a report may be generated. And this would be repeated when `%%a`=f2 and `%%c`=f1. Using `lss` means the comparison is only executed if `%%a` is less than `%%c`. The `/i` ensures the comparison is performed in a case-insensitive manner which should keep the report in alphabetical order on an NTFS drive.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tested yours magoo as I was interested in the certutil method - but I get this: http://i60.tinypic.com/2a6s8k3.png It seems awkward.

Comment: @foxidrive : can't tell what you mean by awkward. Seems quite straight-forward to me!

Comment: 6 duplicate files.  I don't see how that display is straight forward.

Comment: Much betterer.  Check out MC ND's second script in his answer, which might be more useful in a script.  The first filename is aligned at column one and the other duplicates of it are indented.

Answer (score 2):

As this code uses `certutil`, this will work only for windows Vista or later versions of the OS. This will check for duplicates in files of the same size and will only read each involved file only once.

```
@echo off

    rem Configure environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where to search for files
    set "folder=%cd%"

    rem We need a temporary file to hold the size sorted list of files
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"

    rem Change to target folder and work from here
    pushd "%folder%"

    rem Retrieve the list of files with its size and set a environment variable
    rem named as the size of the file. The value of this variable will hold the
    rem number of files with this size
    (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /os *') do (
        echo \%%~za\%%a\
        set /a "sz_%%~za+=1"
    )) >"%tempFile%"

    rem Retrieve the list of sizes that happens more than one time
    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=_=" %%a in ('set sz_') do if %%b gtr 1 if %%a gtr 0 (
        rem Retrive the list of files with the indicated size
        setlocal 
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%c in ('findstr /l /b /c:"\%%a\\" "%tempFile%"') do (
            set "hash="
            for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%e in ('certutil -hashfile "%%d"') do if not defined hash (
                rem For each file, compute its hash. This hash is used as a variable name. 
                rem If the variable is defined, a previous file has the same size and hash
                rem so it is a duplicate
                set "hash=1"
                if defined "%%e" (
                    <nul set /p ".=%%d = "
                    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                    echo(!"%%e"!
                    endlocal
                ) else (
                    rem Store the name of the file in a variable named as the hash of the file
                    set ""%%e"=%%d"
                )
            )

        )
        endlocal
        rem This inner setlocal/endlocal ensures there is no collision between hashes for 
        rem files with different sizes
    ) 

    rem Cleanup
    popd
    del /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal
```

**edited** For a simplified version with no temporary file (the list is created in memory) while still reading only the needed files only once each file, AND as demanded a more readable output

**edited** again to correct a problem with the output of different groups of duplicated for the same file size

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    pushd "%folder%"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /os *') do (
        set /a "sz_%%~za+=1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!fl_%%~za! ") do (endlocal & set "fl_%%~za=%%b "%%a"")
    )

    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=_=" %%a in ('set sz_') do if %%b gtr 1 (
        setlocal  & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%c in ("!fl_%%a!") do ( 
            endlocal 
            for %%d in (%%~c) do (
                if %%a equ 0 ( set "hash=0" ) else ( 
                    set "hash="
                    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%e in ('certutil -hashfile "%%~d"') do if not defined hash set "hash=%%e"
                )

                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                for /f "delims=" %%e in ("!hash!") do if defined hash_"%%~e" (
                    for /f "delims=" %%z in ("!hash_"%%~e"!") do (endlocal & set "hash_"%%~e"=%%z"%%~d";")
                ) else (
                    endlocal & set "hash_"%%~e"="%%~d"="
                )
            )
        )
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%c in ('set hash_ 2^>nul^|find ";"') do (
            set "first=1"
            for %%e in (%%d) do if defined first (set "first=" & echo(%%e) else (echo( = %%e)
        )
        endlocal 
    )
    popd
    endlocal
    exit /b
```

Comment: line 1 `abc.txt = 111zzabc.txt` line 2 `ab.txt = abc.txt` line 3 `zzabc.txt = ab.txt` It doesn't give a clear indication of which files are duplicates.

Comment: @foxidrive, as the files are tested, if the current file is a duplicate of a previous one, the output is  "currentfile = previousfile". But once the file is determined as duplicate, the list can be sent to a separate log, concatenated to a variable, ... it has not been defined how to output the data. With this output, you can delete all the files on the left part of the separator (`=` ) and will maintain one file (in your sample `111zzabc.txt`)

Comment: It doesn't find all duplicates.  It shows me 4 out of 6 duplicate files.

Comment: @foxidrive, for me both versions return all duplicates (with 14 copies of the same file, 13 output lines) silly question, i know it,  but are you sure the files are binary identical?

Comment: Aacini's code shows them as identical as does the `sfk dupfind .` using swiss file knife.  111&zzabc.txt,   111zzabc.txt,   ab & 1.txt,   ab.txt,   abc.txt,   zzabc.txt.   Your code shows 4 lines and is such an unfriendly format that only you know what is what.

Comment: @foxidrive, the problem was my fault and the reason the spaces in file names. Now it works (both versions). Thank you. (second code updated for a readable output)

Answer (score 2):

The solution below process the list of file names just once, so it should run faster.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   if not defined size[%%~Za] (
      set size[%%~Za]="%%a"
   ) else (
      set newName="%%a"
      for %%b in (!size[%%~Za]!) do (
         fc "%%a" %%b >NUL
         if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo "%%a" and %%b are identical
            set "newName="
         )
      )
      if defined newName set "size[%%~Za]=!size[%%~Za]! !newName!"
   )
)
```

If two files are identical, the name of the second one is *not* saved in the lists, so it is not compared again vs. other same size files. If no more than two files may be identical, then this method could be modified so the name of the first file be also removed from the lists (below the `echo ... are identical` command), so the method be even faster.

If you may download a third party program that calculate the MD5 checksum, then it may be used to check if two files are identical instead of `fc` command as foxidrive suggested. This would be faster because the MD5 checksum of each file would be calculated just once and stored in another array (with the file name as index).